# keydown event fire multiple times when i press keys on keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here is a jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgt1suri/a1gc1h4q/.

My problem is that when i press the **a**, **s** and **d** [one key at a time] key so keydown event fire multiple times.

I want that when i press **a**, **s** and **d** [one at a time] key then keydown event fire only once, also i have generate random apple there are **three** apple in my example, so when the top apple shows the **d** keydown event fire only once and hit the apple, when the middle apple shows the **a** event fire only once and hit the apple and so on...

i also post the whole code....

sorry for my bad english.

following is my code.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>boxing</title>
  <!-- Sets initial viewport load and disables zooming  -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ems.css">
  <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements. All other JS at the end of file. -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">Let's do Boxing here...</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div id="timerDiv"></div>
                <br>
                <img class="ring img-responsive" src="img/ring.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="hand img-responsive" src="img/boxing.png" alt="">
                <div class="center">
                  <img style="margin-top:50px;" class="box img-responsive" src="img/app.PNG">
                  <img style="margin-top:150px;" class="box img-responsive" src="img/app.PNG">
                  <img style="margin-top:250px;" class="box img-responsive" src="img/app.PNG">
                </div>
                <center>
                <button id="mybutton" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Start</button>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button id="stop" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Stop</button>
              </center>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
      <script src="js/boxing.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**ems.css**

```
.ring{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
} 
.hand{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 150px;
  left: 200px;
  height:70px;
  width:100px;
} 

.game-btn{
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}

.center{
  text-align: center;
}


.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0px;
  left: 460px;
} 

#timerDiv
{
  width: 180px;
  height: auto;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**boxing.js**

```
// KEYPRESS EVENT
$(document).bind('keydown', 'a', function(){
    var right = $(".hand");
    right.animate({width: '300px'}, 50);
    right.animate({width: '100px'}, 50);
});


$(document).bind('keydown', 's', function(){
    var down = $(".hand");
    down.animate({left: '200px', top:'220px', width: '300px'}, 50);
    down.animate({left: '200px', top:'150px', width: '100px'}, 50);
});

$(document).bind('keydown', 'd', function(){
    var up = $(".hand");
    up.animate({left: '200px', top:'50px', width: '300px'}, 50);
    up.animate({left: '200px', top:'150px', width: '100px'}, 50);
}); 

// RANDOM APPLE
(function loop() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.box').length);
        $('.box').hide().eq(random).show();
        loop()
    }, 500);
}());



// TIMER
$(document).ready(function(){
    var timer = null;
    var time = 0;
    $('#mybutton').click(function() {
        time = 120;      
        showTimer();
        timer = setInterval(showTimer, 1000);
    });

    function showTimer() {
        if (time < 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            return;
        }
        function pad(value) {
            return (value < 10 ? '0' : '') + value;
        }
        function stop() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        };
        $('#stop').click(stop);
        $('#timerDiv').text("Time:- " + Math.floor(time / 60) + ':' + pad(time % 60));
        time--;
    }
});
```

Comment: Which key should fire when they are all pressed at once?

Comment: my problem is when i hit the **a** key in my keyboard it hits the apple **three** times so, i want that when i press the **a** key on my keyboard it hit the **apple** only one time.

Comment: you could possibly work with a timeout there. Have a var set to true on keypress and prevent any action when that var is true. In the first call start a timeout that will set the var false again after e. g. 300 ms

Comment: can you please add that code in **jsfiddle**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are not getting the keycodes from the event. So with your listeners, every animation is done with every keypress. With 3 listeners, that's 3 animations done.
You can move all functions into one single function and have a switch with the keycodes. To get the keycodes of certain characters, you can just add a

```
console.log(e.which)
```

Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a1gc1h4q/2/